# Unable to find number of rows in table using Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

When i am trying to find number of tr(class-tr-heading) in the 1st table,i am getting 2 tr as a result if i use Xpath(working fine with CSS Selector-returns 1 tr)

```
<div class="large 20 columns">
  <table class="Red"><tbody>
    <tr class="tr-heading"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody></table>
  <table class="Red"><tbody>
    <tr class="tr-heading"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Below one return two tr,

```
    WebElement tbl=dr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='large 20 columns']/table[1]/tbody"));
    List<WebElement> trs=tbl.findElements(By.xpath("//tr[@class='tr-heading']"));
    System.out.println(trs.size());
```

This below code returns single tr,

```
WebElement tbl=dr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='large 20 columns']/table[1]/tbody"));
List<WebElement> trs1=tbl.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr[class='tr-heading']"));
System.out.println(trs1.size());
```

It seems Xpath is taking the whole div and returns two tr.Can you please tell me why this difference is and how do i have to do using xpath.

Comment: Both xpaths are same so its obvious that it will return you 2 as size and yes it considering whole div.

Comment: why not find in one xpayh: `//div[@class='large 20 columns']/table[1]/tbody/tr[@class='tr-heading']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dot(.)as it Selects the current node

```
    WebElement tbl=dr.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='large 20 columns']/table[1]/tbody"));
    List<WebElement> trs=tbl.findElements(By.xpath(".//tr[@class='tr-heading']"));
     System.out.println(trs.size());
   //Now it will print out 1 as in the current node there is only one tr tagwith the specified class name
```